# What's role of Device-File-Explorer in Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-sharedpreferences, android-studio-3.0, android-device-monitor

Android Studio 3.0 has a feature about [Device-File-Explorer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer.html) which can help us view files on Android device. it's exciting for non-rooted devices.I know Android Studio actually uses such as `adb exec-out run-as` command to extract files.

Here is a capture:
[image]

As you see, there is a column called `Permissions`. **I want to know what role of `Device-File-Explorer`.

One more, if we have **write permission** can we write something to a file such as `SharedPreference` file?

## EDIT

In fact I want to know `Device-File-Explorer`'s permission such as the owner or group or others.

Comment: "I want to know what role of Device-File-Explorer" -- the role is to be able to explore the filesystem of a device or emulator. This is a replacement for the file manager that was part of DDMS (in Eclipse) and the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: @CommonsWare I update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Device File Explorer allows you to view, copy, and delete files on
>   an Android device. This is useful when examining files that are
>   created by your app or if you want to transfer files to and from a
>   device.

Note: Most device data is not visible unless you are using a rooted device or an emulator with a standard Android (AOSP) system image (not one of the Google APIs or Google Play system images). And when using a connected device, be sure you enable USB debugging.

> if we have write permission can we write something to a file such as
>   SharedPreference file?

**No**

[image]

check [this descriptions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825304/Accessing-internal-data-on-Android-device)

Example:

> drwxrw—x means:
>
> File type: d (Directory),
>
> Owner permission : rwx (Read/Write/Execute),
>
> Group permission : rwx (Read/Write/Execute),
>
> World permission : --x (Only Execute), cannot read the internal data
>   of the directory, or write into it.

Comment: As you see my device is not rooted.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: So Device-File-Explorer has a world permission, right?

Comment: no, but what ever permission it  has it will display.

Comment: But you do not answer me the role of Device-File-Explorer.

Comment: The Device File Explorer allows you to view, copy, and delete files on an Android device.